# How do I change the server name destination dynamically on a SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS that should be execute since the server and invoke since a client.
The SSIS copies the data from the server to the client, but the client's name can change, so how can I change the server name destination with the name of the client that invokes the SSIS?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the server name in a variable and have your connection strings built from an expression rather than stored statically.

The first response to the question [on this forum post](http://p2p.wrox.com/sql-server-2005/63110-dynamic-connectionstring-ssis.html)  details the steps you'll need to take.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure your SSIS package to read variables from various sources such as environment variables, XML files, the system registry or a SQL database table.  Check out package configurations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx).  If you setup your SSIS package to read the client name from a configuration variable instead of hardcoding it in the package you should be able to change it at runtime.

[This link](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_2005_making_ssis_packages_portable.htm) has some information on how to read SSIS configuration from an XML configuration file.

Comment: Agreed-package configurations would definitely be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I use a script task and then dynamically change the connection string by getting it from a variable

For example

```
Dts.Connections("FlatFileCSV").ConnectionString = SomeVariable
```

In your case the name of the connectionstring won't be FlatFileCSV but something else